# Quick Question about Recursion in c

Tags: c, scanf

I have a question about recursion. My code is pretty simple. It looks like:

```
void test();

int main(void) {
    test();
}

void test() {
    char c;
    printf("Are you happy?\n");
    printf("Enter a y for yes, or an n for no\n");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if(c == 'n' ) {
        test();
    } else {
        printf("That's Awesome!");
    }
}
```

I want to have it so if you keep hitting n, it runs the method again and asks you for input again and will keep repeating until you hit a y. This works once but after the method is called again for some reason it automatically prints out the else stmt. Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't need recursion, a simple loop would work.

Comment: Please take time to indent code. More apparent effort makes more people more willing to provide help/insight.

Comment: Okay I will next time thank you pst.

Answer (score 3):

Change `"%c"` to `"%c "` so it will eat the newline.

More generally, using `scanf` for user input doesn't work too well, there are lots of surprises like this.

Comment: Hmm. When I try this I have to key my answer twice initially. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You led me to the answer. When I changed "%c" to " %c". It worked! thanks

Comment: It seems like the output is lagging behind the input, or something. Not sure why. I would just use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont't need any recursion, a do-while loop will do the job just fine.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void test();

 int main(void) {
   test();
 }

 void test() {
   char c;
   do {
     printf("Are you happy?\n");
     printf("Enter a y for yes, or an n for no\n");
     scanf("%c", &c);
   } while (c != 'y');
   printf("That's Awesome!");
 }
```

If you want to use recursion here:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void test();

 int main(void) {
   test();
   printf("That's Awesome!");
 }

 void test() {
   char c;
   printf("Are you happy?\n");
   printf("Enter a y for yes, or an n for no\n");
   scanf("%c", &c);

   if (c != 'y') test();
 }
```

Comment: But he asked how to do this with recursion :/